# To what extent were Jinnah's statements and speeches before 1938 recorded? Have they been digitized?

Tags: india, pakistan

[Jinnah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Ali_Jinnah)'s speeches and statements from the 1938 Patna conference onwards are well recorded, and are available relatively easily. But Jinnah maintained an active political life even before that, and his positions from that period (before 1938) are not so accessible.

In this context, is there a record (digitized or otherwise) of Jinnah's statements.

I am specifically interested in the speech Jinnah gave at the 1938 Muslim League conference in Patna. There are excerpts from that (extempore?) speech floating around. But is anyone in possession of the full text of the speech.
Cheers